# ZFS rpool full, cant do anything

Tags: zfs, opensolaris

I have a huge problem, my rpool is full, so when i boot, i have tons of "no space on device" in my shell. No way to log, ssh server is down.

So i decided to boot with opensolaris Live cd and mount rpool, using those topics:

[Open Indiana topic](http://openindiana.org/pipermail/openindiana-discuss/2010-November/001482.html)

and this one:
[Orcale blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/avinashjoshi/entry/mount_opensolaris_zfs_partition_and)

But i cannot mount rpool/ROOT/solaris because i cannot do this command line:

```
 zfs set mountoint=/a rpool/ROOT/solaris
```

Because i'have got an **zfs cannot set property "out of space"**...i am stuck...

Another strange thing its that **zpool import -f -R /a rpool** succeed, and when i launcg **df -g** i can see the mount, it tells me that 48G are used 100% of the capacity.But when i **ls -al /a** there is only **etc** and **export** empty directories. No files, nothing that i can delete to make space.

I really dont know what to do, any help will be great.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you've succeeded in mounting the pool using an alternate mountpoint with `zpool import -R /mnt poolname` your question is really about what's using up the space, not how to change the mountpoint. Instead of using df for space accounting (which only adds up the size of files without any awareness of compression, dedup, snapshots, async destroy, etc) you should probably be running `zfs list` and `zfs list -t snapshot`.  Probably your current version of your root filesystem is only 48G, but you may have other filesystems (e.g. one for /export/home) or have old snapshots taking up space. You can inspect a snapshot by browsing to it (`cd .zfs/` from the root of that particular filesystem).

Comment: I have browsed all the folder even the hidden (like .zfz) but nothing inside... By the way, i have dropped my solaris system and install ubuntu with btrfs. Thanks